# Wordpress admin not showing up in author dropdown

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, author

I recently moved my Wordpress to a new ISP. Now, my Wordpress user account (which is the admin) doesn't show up in the dropdown list of authors when I create a new page. My admin account shows up properly on the users page. I have tried deactivating all the plugins, but the problem still persists. What can I do to make my admin user account show up in the dropdown author list?

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that I found.

1. Create a second account with admin permissions.
2. Log in to the second account.
3. Change the permissions for the first account to "Editor."
4. Log out of the second account.
5. Log in to the first account.
6. The first account shows up in the author dropdown menu.
7. Log out of the first account.
8. Log in to the second account.
9. Set the permission for the first account back to "Admin."
10. Log out of the second account.
11. Log in with to the first account.
12. When creating a new page, the first account continues to show up in the
    author dropdown list.

Setting the account to a lower permission, and then back to the admin permission seems to reset whatever the issue was in the database.